# Tkinter colorchooser runs without even importing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk

root = Tk()
root.title("Tkinter window")

def c():
    print("Yay")
    # a = colorchooser.askcolor()
    # l = Label(root, text = a[1], bg = a[1])
    # l.pack(pady = 10)
    # root.configure(bg = a[1])

btn = Button(root, text = "Pick a colour", command = c)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Somehow this outputs this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JWLb.png)

I dont understand what is happening because I'm not even importing colorchoose from tkinter.

Note: I did install tkcolorpicker a seperate package but uninstalled that straight after this strange error and cleared my pip cache.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce, so the problem can be with `tkcolorpicker`. Are you sure that it is actually connected to this? Have you just tried importing tkinter and seing if it does anything?

Comment: do you run it normally `python script.py` ? Maybe you run it in IDE created with `tkinter` - like `IDLE` or `Thony` - and it already imported this module.

Comment: @БогданОпир I have uninstalled it and this problem is still being produced. I just made a blank file only importing tkinter using 'from tkinter import *' and the colourpicker has not been displayed - its only when I run the mainloop() that this is occuring

Comment: @furas I am running it using Visual Studio. When using the terminal, the same error is produced.

Comment: it is strange behavior. Maybe you have file `tkinter.py` and it loads other modules. You can check `print(tkinter.__file__)` to see if it load standard module or other file. OR maybe you have to files - you edit one file but you run other file without changes.

Comment: @furas I have no file called tkinter and the print statement produces an error as 'tkinter is not defined'

Comment: you have to use `import tkinter` and then `print(tkinter.__file__)` and then you can use this path to see source code.

Comment: @furas this output is produced `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py`

Comment: it seems it use correct file. I don't have other ideas. Maybe the only idea - use Python 3.7 instead of Python 3.8 which is still fresh version and it may have bugs.

Comment: Maybe a really stupid question: Are you running the correct file. I know that in VSC you can press the up arrow in the terminal to rerun a script. Try adding ```print(os.path.abspath(__file__))```.

Comment: This can’t possibly happen. There must be more to the problem. The only rational explanation is that you aren’t running the code you think you are running.

Comment: Here's an interesting link, containing ways to screw up your import. I've fallen victim to some of those as well. And I'm just starting out. Even when it's useless for your problem, it's an interesting read. http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Answer (score 0):

For me i am not getting that colourchoose 
i just remove comment code and make it look clean.

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk

root = Tk()
root.maxsize(100,100)
root.minsize(100,100)

root.title("Tkinter window")

def c():
    print("Yay")

btn = Button(root, text = "Pick a colour", command = c)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Try this maybe you get answer of you question Or maybe is working with tkcolorpicker.

Comment: This doesn't really address the asker's question, which is about why tkinter functions work without importing them.